# Avoid for-loop: Define blocks of actions within a time range

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to define blocks of actions - so I want to group together all actions for a single id that take place less than 30 days since the last action.  If  it's more than 30 days since the last action, then I'd increment the label by one (so label 2, 3, 4...).  Every new id would start at 1 again.

Here's the data:

```
dat = data.frame(cbind(
  id = c(rep(1,2), rep(16,3), rep(17,24)),
  ##day_id is the action date in %Y%m%d format - I keep it as numeric but could potentially turn to a date.
  day_id = c(20130702, 20130121, 20131028, 20131028, 20130531, 20140513, 20140509,    
         20140430, 20140417, 20140411, 20140410, 20140404,
         20140320, 20140313, 20140305, 20140224, 20140213, 20140131, 20140114,  
         20130827, 20130820, 20130806, 20130730, 20130723,
         20130719, 20130716, 20130620, 20130620, 20130614 ),
  ###diff is the # of days between actions/day_ids
  diff =c(NA,162,NA,0,150,NA,4,9,13,6,1,6,15,7,8,9,11,13,17,140,7,14,
         7,7,4,3,26,0,6),
  ###Just a flag to say whether it's a new id
  new_id = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
))
```

I've done it with a for loop and managed to avoid loops within loops (see below) but can't seem to get rid of that outer loop.  Of course, it gets extremely slow with thousands of ids.  In the example below, 'call_block' is what I'm trying to reproduce but without the for loop.  Can anyone help me get this out of a loop??

```
max_days = 30
r = NULL
for(i in unique(dat$id)){
  d = dat$diff[dat$id==i]
  w = c(1,which(d>=max_days) , length(d)+1)
  w2 = diff(w)

  r = c(r,rep(1:(length(w)-1), w2))
}
dat$call_block = r
```

Thank you!

Comment: To understand, assuming that for a given "id" you had `dat$diff` like the following `x`: `x = c(NA,5,10,34,6,8,15,50,3,3,100,23,4)`, would you want to return `c(1, cumsum((x >= 30)[-1]) + 1)`?

Comment: AWESOME - it worked!!  
    
    library(data.table)
    f = function(x){ 
       ret = c(1, cumsum((x >= 30)[-1]) + 1)
       return(ret = ret)
    }

    df = data.table(dat)
    df2 = df[,list(call_block= f(diff)), by = id]

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting @alexis_laz's answer here to close out the question

```
library(data.table)
f = function(x){ 
    ret = c(1, cumsum((x >= 30)[-1]) + 1) 
    return(ret = ret) 
}
df = data.table(dat)
df2 = df[,list(call_block= f(diff)), by = id]
```